# NumberFormatter não funciona o MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2

Tags: php, valor-monetário

Bom uso a biblioteca NumberFormatter do php para trabalhar com conversão, mas estou tendo um problema para converte números com muitos dígitos após o .

Exemplo:

```
$valores = '54.98054562';

$moeda1 = new NumberFormatter('pt_BR', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$moeda1->setAttribute( NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);

$valores = $moeda1->formatCurrency($valores, 'BRL');

echo $valores;
```

Ele me retorna 54,981 e preciso que me retorne 54,98.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque `MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS` por `MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS` para definir o número máximo de digitos de uma fração, no caso 2.

```
<?php
$valores = '54.98054562';

$moeda1 = new NumberFormatter('pt_BR', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$moeda1->setAttribute( NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);

$valores = $moeda1->formatCurrency($valores, 'BRL');

echo $valores;
```

Comment: muito obrigado ;)

Answer (score 2):

Está especificando mínimo de 2 dígitos para casa decimal.

Deveria especificar máximo de 2 dígitos

```
$moeda1->setAttribute( NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS, 2);
```

consulte: http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php

Comment: muito obrigado ;)